# iOS iPhone iPad limit SSL / HTTPS encryption bits

Tags: ios, encryption, ssl, https

Is there a way to limit the encryption bits / type on the iOS side of an SSL / HTTPS connection?  Say We would like to have the max bits be some number like 1024 or 128, etc.

Can we set the encryption type to DES only?

Comment: why? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why, because.  Please answer the question, yes or no.  If yes if can explain how.

Comment: I'm asking because your question is essentially "how can I make my SSL connection as easy as possible to break?" and that is not generally speaking a good idea.  If there is a specific reason why, then there might be a better solution then making SSL work poorly

Comment: also, are you talking from within an iOS application you've written, or from within Safari? Do you have control of the backend server?

Comment: Ok, there are / were reasons for asking the question otherwise I would not have asked it.  I could also say to make the min 1024 or 2048 bits, etc.  Main question is can the encryption style / bits be controlled from an IOS app when communicating with another machine using SSL and / or HTTPS?  I did not ask "how can I make....".  Please answer the question if at all possible and if it is not too much to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two different aspects of SSL that are addressed in this question:

1. controlling the cipher suite used during the SSL session
2. controlling the key size of the RSA key used in the SSL communication

the first can be controlled if you are using `CFSockets` by using code noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977086/1904979).  Bear in mind you will need to select a ciphersuite that the server actually supports, otherwise SSL won't work.  A list of ciphersuites can be found [here](http://www.thesprawl.org/research/tls-and-ssl-cipher-suites/).  If you want to set DES as a cipher suite (which I strongly, **Strongly** advise against), you would use something like `SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`

the second is out of your hands from a client-side perspective... the key size (1024 bits, 2048 bits, 128bits, etc) is set by the size of the key in the SSL certificate on the server. You can probably use the procedure outlined in the first step to figure out the size of the key from the `SSLContextRef`, then close the connection if you don't get a value you like.

Finally, if you want to do this from within Safari, you are completely [out of luck](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32125/setting-safari-ssl-tls-cipher-suites)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  We have control of the server so no issue there for getting the correct type.  Ok on the bits and the cert.  The  "bits" for our cert is 2048, but does this not only apply to the authentication and not the actual download of the data?  These "bits" are negotiated between the client (iOS) and server?  I guess these were the bits we were looking to "set".  For us, this question is now moot (different path), but just curious from now on.  Also, I know the DES is bad / old, but used it as an example.

Comment: in the second link (with the list of CipherSpecs) you can see a column named "bits" which represents the keysize of the symmetric keys used as a part of the ciphersuite.  so you can specify, say, AES128 vs AES256 and get different keysizes.  The RSA key in the certificate itself is only used for authentication and (usually) key exchange, all of the data is encrypted with a symmetric cipher