# Using SSLSetEnabledCiphers with AFNetworking to disable weak ciphers

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, afnetworking, cfnetwork

I am trying to disable some ciphers (weak) such as single DES, single DES 40 bit etc.

I've tried using this bit of code from [How does one set SSL ciphers when using CFSocket/CFStream in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954971/how-does-one-set-ssl-ciphers-when-using-cfsocket-cfstream-in-cocoa) and from mailing list message [CFNetwork SSL and long blocking delays](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Apple-cdsa/2008/Oct/msg00007.html) but I need access to socket data to get the `CFDataRef`.

Here is the code that I tried to insert in the handshake method in `AFURLConnectionOperation` class:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    CFReadStreamRef stream = [sock getCFReadStream];
    CFDataRef data = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSSLContext);

    // Extract the SSLContextRef from the CFData
    SSLContextRef sslContext;
    CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(SSLContextRef)), &sslContext);

    // Get all enabled ciphers
    size_t numCiphers;
    SSLGetNumberEnabledCiphers(sslContext,&numCiphers);
    SSLCipherSuite ciphers[numCiphers];
    SSLGetEnabledCiphers(sslContext,ciphers,&numCiphers);

    // Create a new cipher array with only non-DH ciphers, and set it
    SSLCipherSuite finalCiphers[numCiphers];
    int numFinalCiphers = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numCiphers; i++) {
        SSLCipherSuite suite = ciphers[i];
        if(!cipherSuiteUsesDH(suite)) {
            finalCiphers[numFinalCiphers] = suite;
            numFinalCiphers++;
        }
    }
    SSLSetEnabledCiphers(sslContext,finalCiphers,numFinalCiphers);
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Unfortunately this is an existing project and it still uses version 1 of AFNetworking.

Comment: Also see [Securing iOS Applications](http://jan0.free.fr/208_securing_ios_applications.pdf). It looks like an interesting talk.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I figured as much that they are different levels of Api and there hoped that there might be a bridge somewhere. I already went through the video, i am hoping to find the sample code though. Is there any other way to disable ciphers?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. So far I have found a way to do that https://twitter.com/abelenko/status/437266477436002304 https://gist.github.com/belenko/d9c29ffbf2dca8a3dd0c but this is use of private APIs and as it is said in comments to twitt it leads to rejection of the app in App Store.

Answer (score 3):

> Using SSLSetEnabledCiphers with AFNetworking to disable weak ciphers

OK, this one piqued my interest because its something I do in other languages, but not Cocoa/CocoaTouch. Its been on my TODO list for some time. The answer is you can't do it when working with the high level objects like `NSURLConnection`.

I could *not* find a way to bridge the gap between `NSURLConnection` and friends and the low level stuff needed to set the cipher suits. If you are interested, the "highest" the low level stuff goes is `CFSocketStream`. So the job is to get `NSURLConnection` to work with a `CFSocketStream` (or access the `CFSocketStream` in the `NSURLConnection`).

I also mirrored your question on Apple's [Network Programming](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/macnetworkprog) mailing list, and both Jens and Quinn confirmed it (Quinn provided the info on `CFSocketStream`). See [Configure socket used by NSURLConnection?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2014/Jul/msg00072.html).

Also, in case you did not realize it, attempting to modify the properties in `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` is too late. By the time you get the authentication challenge, the handshake is already in progress (i.e., the `ClientHello` has already been sent).

If you do manage to find a hack to do it, then please post it.

Comment: I have found a hack on the internet to accomplish that. Please see my comment to the OP's question. I have also read your question in mailing list. This is very unfortunate that there is no API to instruct NSURLConnection to use specific cipher suites or at least minimum SSL/TLS protocol version if we don't have access to underlying sockets. :(