# CFNetwork Anonymous Ciphers?

Tags: ios, ssl, ios7, cfnetwork

Is there any way with CFNetwork to enable anonymous ciphers -- i.e. so we can use SSL connection code to connect to some (weakly protected) servers?

Comment: The question needs substantial work to be clear ob what is being asked. What is "anonymous ciphers" and " (weakly protected) servers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way with CFNetwork to enable anonymous ciphers

Yes. Setting the cipher suite is as easy as:

```
SSLContextRef ctx = NULL;
SSLNewContext(NO /*client*/, &ctx);

SSLCipherSuite cipher = TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA;
SSLSetEnabledCiphers(ctx, &cipher, 1);
...
```

Hooking it up to a higher level object, like `NSURLConnection`, is hard. See [Configure socket used by NSURLConnection?](https://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2014/Jul/msg00072.html) on the Apple Networking mailing list.

Also see [Using SSLSetEnabledCiphers with AFNetworking to disable weak ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002556/using-sslsetenabledciphers-with-afnetworking-to-disable-weak-ciphers).

---

Here are the RADARs that were filled regarding the problem:

- iOS, Apple RADAR 17904439, "Unable to set SSLContext on NSURLConnection and friends"
- OS X, Apple RADAR 17904536, "Unable to set SSLContext on NSURLConnection and friends"
- iOS, OpenRadar 5843780150231040, ["Unable to set SSLContext on NSURLConnection and friends"](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5843780150231040)
- OS X, OpenRadar 5810038887153664, ["Unable to set SSLContext on NSURLConnection and friends"](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5810038887153664)

Comment: Thanks - new to this stuff -- so there's not something like kCFStreamPropertySSLNullCipher? 
SO I just catch the connect event and process the context stuff there??