# Firebase, Retrieving Data: Find all Titles that have 'Status' as 'Open' in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*Main mission is to find all Titles that have 'Status' as 'Open'*

I want to get all the favorTit to an array to be used in indexPath.row

```
func retrieveQuery(){
    var i = 0
    queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("status").queryEqualToValue("Open")
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
        { snapshot in 
            i++
            self.antal = snapshot.children.allObjects.count
            print(self.antal)
            print(snapshot.value.objectForKey("favorTit")!)
            print(i)                
        })  
}
```

Firebase data
https://api.myjson.com/bins/4n5rn

```
{
    "categories": [{
        "altText": "T.ex. StÃ¤dning, Disk, TvÃ¤tt, Matlagning",
        "title": "HushÃ¥ll"
    }, {
        "altText": "T.ex.  ",
        "title": " "
    }, {
        "altText": " ",
        "title": " "
    }, {
        "altText": " ",
        "title": " "
    }, {
        "altText": " ",
        "title": " "
    }, {
        "altText": " ",
        "title": " "
    }, {
        "altText": " ",
        "title": " "
    }],
    "favors": {
        "1": {
            "catId": 1,
            "favorBudget": 212121,
            "favorDes": "Gfdgsfdsg",
            "favorDueDate": "Today",
            "favorGeo": [-7.090910999999999, 107.668887],
            "favorLocation": ["West Java, Indonesia"],
            "favorTit": "RÃ¤tt",
            "status": "Open",
            "user": "2872e074-e45a-4d7a-a9c7-83fad641aa62",
            "workCompletion": "In person"
        },
        "2": {
            "catId": 1,
            "favorBudget": 4000,
            "favorDes": "Gfdgf",
            "favorDueDate": "Today",
            "favorGeo": [34.506668, -81.948334],
            "favorLocation": ["Laurens County Airport, Laurens, SC 29360, USA"],
            "favorTit": "RÃ¤tt",
            "status": "Open",
            "user": "2872e074-e45a-4d7a-a9c7-83fad641aa62",
            "workCompletion": "In person"
        },
        "3": {
            "catId": 1,
            "favorBudget": 4000,
            "favorDes": "Gfdgf",
            "favorDueDate": "Today",
            "favorGeo": [34.506668, -81.948334],
            "favorLocation": ["Laurens County Airport, Laurens, SC 29360, USA"],
            "favorTit": "RÃ¤tt",
            "status": "Ongoing",
            "user": "2872e074-e45a-4d7a-a9c7-83fad641aa62",
            "workCompletion": "In person"
        },
        "7fd547be-7836-42e2-a74f-2f2a39baee43": {
            "favorTit": "Test",
            "favors": {
                "furniture assmebly": {
                    "favorBudget": 60000,
                    "favorDes": "Assemly My ikea",
                    "favorDueDate": "Today",
                    "favorGeo": [39.0311755, -77.5283463],
                    "favorLocation": ["Polen Farm Blvd, Ashburn, VA 20148, USA"],
                    "favorTit": "Den ska bli fixad kom snabbt",
                    "workCompletion": "In person"
                },
                "handyman": {
                    "favorBudget": 43434,
                    "favorDes": "Install TV-Mount",
                    "favorDueDate": "Today",
                    "favorGeo": [49.0068901, 8.4036527],
                    "favorLocation": ["Karlsruhe, Germany"],
                    "favorTit": "JAllah",
                    "workCompletion": "In person"
                },
                "photography": {
                    "favorBudget": 6000,
                    "favorDes": "Jag vill ha ett album med bilder pÃ¥ mig och omgivningenðŸ’ª Du ska inte sÃ¤ga mycket under brÃ¶llopet men det ska vara vackra bilder",
                    "favorDueDate": "Within a week",
                    "favorGeo": [55.6178043, 12.98939],
                    "favorLocation": ["Krankajen 36, 211 12 MalmÃ¶, Sverige"],
                    "favorTit": "take a photo of my wedding",
                    "workCompletion": "In person"
                },
                "trÃ¤dgÃ¥rd": {
                    "favorBudget": 2000,
                    "favorDes": "Jag vill ha den klippt med en sax",
                    "favorDueDate": "Within a week",
                    "favorGeo": [35.86166, 104.195397],
                    "favorLocation": ["China"],
                    "favorTit": "Klipp min grÃ¤smatta",
                    "workCompletion": "In person"
                }
            },
            "status": "Done"
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "2872e074-e45a-4d7a-a9c7-83fad641aa62": {
            "email": "fille382@gmail.com",
            "name": "lol",
            "phone": "123567890",
            "provider": "password"
        },
        "5f0fb39e-620a-4cd1-9e6a-2b7ae9baaf71": {
            "email": "lol@gmail.com",
            "name": "Gunn Bellander",
            "phone": "0735158548",
            "provider": "password"
        },
        "7fd547be-7836-42e2-a74f-2f2a39baee43": {
            "about": "Johan my name is Filip Bellander and i am creating this beautiful app right now the about page is here so the user can quickly reach its target by writing about himself and his completions ",
            "comments": {
                "4354352": {
                    "comment": "He did everything even cleaned up after himself",
                    "stars": 3,
                    "tasktitle": "Do everything"
                },
                "423489054": {
                    "comment": "Yes very nice",
                    "stars": 1,
                    "tasktitle": "call my phone"
                },
                "5435486956": {
                    "comment": "It was very clean",
                    "stars": 3,
                    "tasktitle": "Clean room"
                },
                "54643654654": {
                    "comment": "He did a great job wiping all whipcream from the luggage",
                    "stars": 4,
                    "tasktitle": "Whipe dat"
                }
            },
            "completed": 90,
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "name": "Filip Bellander",
            "phone": "0735158548",
            "posted": 81,
            "provider": "password",
            "rating": 5,
            "reviews": 1337,
            "skills": "App programmer, Visual designer DriversDriverslicenseDriverslicenseDriverslicenseDriverslicenselicense no"
        },
        "bdc6c3f8-764a-4468-825a-408f53695b24": {
            "email": "Elisabet.bellander@gmail.com",
            "name": "Elisabet Bellander",
            "phone": "0721645504",
            "provider": "password"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Filip. Please add the code as text not an image.

Comment: and your Firebase structure as text as well please (no images). Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh. and... .Value retrieves all nodes matching the query so you will need to iterate over them to get the discreet nodes...   for child in snapshot.children {}

Comment: @Jay Updated information

Comment: @adolfosrs Updated information

Answer (score 0):

From your code you should already have the Open Titles array in your snapshot.

```
if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    self.items = result
}
```

Then your `TableView` will depend on how you are implementing it. There is some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246602/populating-uitableviewcontroller-with-firebase-data-swift-xcode-7) and [here](http://rshankar.com/ios-swift-firebase-demo/).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  ...
  let cellDict = items[indexPath.row]
  ...
  return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make an array by inserting the string at index 0 everytime it runs by using the code below

```
queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("status").queryEqualToValue("Open")
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
        { snapshot in

            self.antal = snapshot.children.allObjects.count
            print(self.antal)

            var titles = snapshot.value.objectForKey("favorTit") as! String
            var description = snapshot.value.objectForKey("favorDes") as! String
            var budget = snapshot.value.objectForKey("favorBudget") as! Double

            self.openTitles.insert(titles, atIndex: 0)
            self.openDescription.insert(description, atIndex: 0)
            self.openBudget.insert(budget, atIndex: 0)

            print(self.openTitles)
            print(self.openDescription)


        })
```